# Inserting font awesome icon using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, font-awesome

I am working on a WordPress site using a jobs application plugin. I want to add a font awesome icon to a button using javascript. The hml code I can see for the button is.

```
<input type = "button" class="application_button button" value="apply for job"></input>
```

which I think I need to make the following for the icon to show.

```
<input type = "button" class="application_button button" value="apply for job"> <i class = "fas fa-chevron-right"></i></input>
```

the JavaScript I have added to achieve this is,

```
 var d1 = document.querySelector('.application_button');
d1.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', '<i class="fas fa-chevron-right"></i>');
```

When I console.log(d1); I can see that I have got the code I want. But the icon does not show. If I use 'afterend' then I do see the icon, but outside the button.

I seem so close, but so far away.

Any advice?

Comment: Input is a **void tag** (like `<br>` etc...). Closing it with `</input>` is invalid markup.

Answer (score 1):

As I said in comments:

> [INPUT is a **void element**](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/syntax.html#elements-2) (like `<br>` etc...). Closing it with `</input>` is **invalid markup**.

Therefore, use a BUTTON element

```html
 <button type="button">Apply for job <i class="fas fa-chevron-right"></i></button>

 <button type="button"><i class="fas fa-chevron-left"></i> Go back</button>
```

---

## Using an icon inside the Value of an INPUT

#### JavaScript solution

If you **really cannot** change the markup from `<input>` to `<button>` element, than you could define the `font-family` with the desired fallbacks right in CSS, and **concatenate** the current INPUT value to the **unicode representation** of the Font Awesome icon `el.value += " \uf054"`:

<sub>Example using both **Google fonts and Font Awesome**:</sub>

```js
const addChevron = el => el.value += " \uf054";
document.querySelectorAll('input.button').forEach(addChevron);
```

```css
.button {
  font-family: 'Montserrat', 'Font Awesome 5 Free', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 900; /* Needed for font awesome to work... */
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.12.1/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

<input class="button" type="button" value="Submit to win!">
```

If you use some Google font, or you want to inherit the font, no worries, pick one:

```css
font-family: 'Some Google Font', 'Font Awesome 5 Free', sans-serif;
font-family: inherit, 'Font Awesome 5 Free', sans-serif;
font-family: 'Font Awesome 5 Free', sans-serif;
```

you get the idea.

---

#### HTML solution

If you don't want to use JavaScript than you could use the unicode representation right inside the `value` attribute: `&#xf054;`

```css
.button {
  font-family: 'Font Awesome 5 Free', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 900; /* Needed for font awesome to work... */
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.12.1/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<input class="button" type="button" value="Submit to win! &#xf054;">
```

Answer (score 0):

Font awesome icons rely on creating their icons on a pseudo element `::before`, which creates the icon via that pseudo element's `content` property.

`input` tags cannot have `content`, thus using font awesome icons on them cannot work.

Instead of

```
<input type="button" class="application_button button" value="apply for job"></input>
```

which, btw, is **invalid HTML** since `input` cannot have a closing tag `</input>` for the same reason `::before` doesn't work on it, use

```
<button type="button" class="application_button button">apply for job</button>
```

Since you need the icon at the right side of the button, you can do that either by adding an element at the end that carries the CSS classes `fas fa-chevron-right`:

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.12.1/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<button type="button" class="application_button button">apply for job <i class="fas fa-chevron-right"></i></button>
```

or by adding this simple CSS:

```css
.application_button.button.fas.fa-chevron-right::before { float: right; margin-left: 5px; }
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.12.1/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<button type="button" class="application_button button fas fa-chevron-right"> apply for job</button>
```

Which method you use is up to you, I personally prefer to solve layout-related problems with CSS rather than applying otherwise unnecessary additional markup.

Comment: **Don't add the `fas` classes to the button**. The arrow should be on the **right**. Therefore use another element inside the button - after the text: `apply for job <i class="fas fa-chevron-right"></i>` - Also this will help not to mess with font-family fallbacks since the text is inside the `fas`... (like in your case)

Comment: No, there's no *if*.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan I've accounted for that by adding additional solutions. Please reconsider your downvote as my answer has all the correct information to solve the given problem, as well as an explanation of what is going wrong in OP's attempt.

Comment: Most people coming to your answer will copy-paste your first example which is *not* the way to do it. And also, don't mess with unnecessary floats.

Comment: I don't agree with your *don't mess with floats* statement; otherwise I have removed the first suggestion.

Comment: The HTML I am having to use is coded within one of the plugins template files. Before adding my code there is no closing input tag. But once I add the code, the browser is adding the closing input tag. I cannot change the input tag to button I dont think without messing with the template and I was trying to avoid that.

I will have to add using css pseudo classes, but I read that this can be bad practice to do it like this. But I had problems with this early on and I guess the reason could be as connexo says above, that I cannot use fa if I am dealing with an input tag.

Comment: Floats are a beast on their own. If you really want to use a CSS class in order to avoid putting extra `<i>` markup (I don't see the reason why though) than create a class that uses the 'font-awesome' font family with the expected icon code `content: "\HEX"` character and assigns it to the `::after` pseudo...

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan Lean, semantic markup. That's the reason. You keep the HTML as clean as possible. Presentation is CSS' job.